# Importing an image file, adding it to an ArrayList, and then displaying the images sequentially

Tags: java

I'm trying to import an image file using `JFileChooser` add the image to an `ArrayList`. Then finally have display the images sequentially on a `JPanel` when a button is pressed.  Does anyone know how I could do this?  I'm new to java.

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to start looking into some Java GUI tutorials first.

Comment: Your question is very general and covers a lot of ground. To prevent us from having to re-write tutorials that have already been written, please tell us, what have you done? What do you know? What specifically confuses you?

Comment: *"Does anyone know how I could do this?"*  Yes.  (Should I enter 'yes' as the answer?)

Answer (score 2):

Break it down into steps.

Task 1: Import an image file using JFileChooser.
Get the file object chosen
Use [ImageIO.read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.File%29)(file) to get a buffered image.

Task 2: Add image to an array list

```
List<BufferedImage> images = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>()
images.add(image);
```

Task 3: Display an image in a JPanel

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();
JButton button = new JButton();
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(images.get(0));
button.setIcon(icon);

p.add(button);
```

Task 4: Adding buttons that advance through your images

```
JButton advance = new JButton();
advance.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    advanceImage();
  }
};
```